# StackoverflowExcepton in Spring message i18n ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, internationalization

I am enabling message i18n in my Spring web app. For this, I have below code in my `servlet.xml`

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages/message"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
```

After adding above code, as soon as I hit my application in browser, I get below exception log:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/ERP-Web] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.getMergedProperties(ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.java:235)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.resolveCodeWithoutArguments(ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessageInternal(AbstractMessageSource.java:209)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessageFromParent(AbstractMessageSource.java:257)
```

where last 2 lines were repeated 100s of times and gives me `StackoverflowException`.

Exactly same exception is coming when I am using `ResourceBundleMessageSource` class.

My spring version is `4.3.6.RELEASE`.

Below is content of my properties file

```
action.add.success = New {0} added successfully.
action.add.failure = Some error occurred in adding new {0}. Please try again later or contact administrator.
```

Sample project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/aakashagarwal86/SpringMessageSource)

Comment: add your messages property file , as in my case both with and without classpath working correctly

Comment: It loaded the properties file, but gave me exception as soon as I hit my application from browser.

Comment: very strange. Do you have a mini project to reproduce the error so that is possible to look into it ?

Comment: uhh...will try and give you a mini project. May take a day or two though. Apologies for this delay guys

Comment: Sample project added @TestoTestini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strange situation ;-)

The fundamental problem is that the `messageSource` gets auto-wired to itself (in the `parentMessageSource` property) because you use `default-autowire="byType"` this causes the stackoverflow exceptions for unknown message codes that messes up everything. Must say that logback adds mess to the mess as sometimes seems that the exception happens in its code, Log4J handles it better.

[Autowiring is not good for big projects](https://blog.frankel.ch/my-case-against-autowiring/#gsc.tab=0), and this your situation is a classical case of why, however if you must use it change the `messageSource` bean adding the following:

```
       <property name="parentMessageSource"><null/></property>
```

In this way you wire yourself the parent and no autowiring happens.

This restores the normal situation in which not found messages are reported with a `NoSuchMessageException`

Then:

1. In controller you must request `hello.world` message, not `message`
2. You are missing a default resource, that is a no-locale-suffix file that represents the default locale or your application. In your case would be `messages/message.properties` To be simple the default locale of your application is that one for which you have all messages. Start with that and then add new languages (that might be incomplete).

Answer (score 2):

I have tested your sample code in github and when running it has shown the error described, then modify the following:

Config:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages/message"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

Class:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getMessage() {
    String msg = messageSource.getMessage("hello.world", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
    return msg;
}
```

**hello.word** is the property with text in your file with name **message_en.properties**.

With this modifications the code run.

**Edit for unknown message codes:**

I tried with **unknown message codes** and the error was repeated, so I look at the registry and found that there could be more than one beans with the same name (**potential circular references**), but I have not detected why this happens, but if you It needs to work you have to rename the beans like this.

```
<bean id="myMessageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages/message"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
```

and then use:

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource myMessageSource;
```

but i think this not resolve the principal problem with the circular potential error.

Comment: yes but he will still get the stackoverflow exception for unknown message codes

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

As far as I run your demo project:

- Remove `default-autowire="byType"`, which will set your message source's parent to itself, which causes stackoverflow;
- Avoid `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()`, which relay on system default locale;
- Use right basename, which is different for `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` and `ResourceBundleMessageSource` which solves following warning;

  > ResourceBundle [messages/message] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name messages/message, locale en_US

**[Runnable example](https://github.com/zzt93/resourceBoudleDemo)**

---

#### StackTrace

As far as I could see from your stack trace, you may have three problems:

- You don't supply arguments, but your property needs it;
- The message source you have has cyclic dependency with its parent, which causes the `StackOverflow` (because `AbstractMessageSource` has a model like classloader, i.e. delegation to parent if it can't resolve);
- I am not sure whether your properties is really found by message source, if it found, even with cyclic dependency, it will not `StackOverflow`;

#### Suggestions

- When it comes to why there exists cyclic dependency, I can't tell whether it is a bug of spring or mis-configuration according to current info;
- If you are not convenient to provide a example project, you may try `4.1.6 Relase`, which I tried, works fine;
- You may set log level to DEBUG or set breakpoint, to see whether you property file is really loaded;

Comment: Sample project added. It seems to be 2nd of your stated possible problems. Although it's not determined yet if it's a problem in my code or a bug in Spring library. Although the latter is unlikely.

Comment: I cannot downgrade spring version, much development is done already and it leads to cascade events where I would need to downgrade `Hibernate` version and re-code my DAO layer.

Comment: ahh...you suggested me to try `4.1.6. Release`, while I am using `4.3.6 Release`. That's why my previous comment

Comment: @Aakash so now any problem?

Comment: As I am using `Spring` autowiring, can't remove `default-autowire="byType"`. This is a required property, else my app won't work.

Comment: @Aakash Remove this attribute will not remove autowire, it just change the default way spring autowire. By the way, what's your error if you remove this, we can't help if you just say 'app won't work'. Try and give us the error.

Comment: 'app won't work' means that autowiring does not happen and app throws NPE everywhere. We are using autowiring by type, not by name.

Comment: @Aakash you may open up another question and give us a demo project which has the error. I can't reproduce what you said with your current demo.

Comment: sure @tony, will give that in a couple of days. Thank you for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The way you should use the `ResourceBundleMessageSource` is setting the path to the messages files on the `basename` property.

For example, if you have two messages files:

- `messages_en.properties`
- `messages_es.properties`

located at `resources` folder. Your bean configuration should be something like:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>
```

Where `messages` is the prefix of the name of both files.

Maybe the `Exception` is thrown because Spring id trying to load the classpath automatically, and you have it included too, so it tries to load it again and again...

You can find a working example on [Mkyong's](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-resource-bundle-with-resourcebundlemessagesource-example/).

Comment: My app did not load the files unless I use `classpath:` in value. It throws the above exception whether it loads the files or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in my `applicationContext.xml` file:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:i18n/message" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Note that i put the properties files in the follwoing path :

```
src/main/resources/i18n/message_en.properties
```